# Register app to open image files

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have successfully registered my app to open PDF files by including the following in my info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

However, I cannot seem to register my app to open any image files, I have tried to register not only for the base image UTI, but also specific types like png and jpg. Is it possible to register to open image files?

Answer (score 2):

Bad news - cannot be done. Wish these things would be stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

open plist with Source code and add this for document.

```
<dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>All Files</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.content</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
```

i hope this usefull for you.

Answer (score -1):

Open the plist with an editor...

Capitalization, etc is critical, recommend specifying both lower case and upper case file extensions.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
<string>jpg</string>
<string>JPG</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Images</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Editor</string>
```

Then save the file.  App should now be registered to handle this type of file.