# Register to support image files with iOS app

Tags: ios

Hi I would like to register to support image files in my app; so when user tap on the action button in iPhone's photo app, my app icon would show up within the "open with ..." menu. I have the following in my info.plist

```
<dict>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Alternate</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
     <array>
        <string>public.png</string>
     </array>
</dict>


<dict>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Alternate</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
      <array>
         <string>public.jpeg</string>
      </array>
</dict>
```

but can't get it to show up in that menu. is this the correct way? please help thank you!!

Comment: Your question is not clear... ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is the purpose of adding that plist here ?

Comment: Have you tried using the "public.image" UTI instead of public.jpeg and public.png?

Comment: hi Sven, yes I did, but no luck :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register app to open image files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481534/register-app-to-open-image-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this it works for me

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>png</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>jpeg</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>tiff</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.tiff</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </array>
```

more information in this link 
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Jun/msg00747.html

Comment: hi Pran! thanks for your answer! I tried and still not working...is it all the code you need to make it work? do I have to do other settings else where?

Comment: still not able to work...so when you tap on the action button in Photo app it would show your app name / icon?

Comment: Hi Chris Lin i updated my answer can please check no more setting this will work.

Comment: yes exactly .my app supports more than 10 type of files .try like this  send image to mail open that mail in mailApp.

Comment: Does anyone had some luck with this on iOS7?

Comment: Does anyone had some luck with this on iOS8???
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419177/ios-8-open-image-in-my-app-from-another-apps